# how to include table footer when exporting to pdf in angular ui grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Hi I am displaying price field in the table and its total is displayed in the table footer.  I noticed that only the aggregated value of price does not go to pdf.  How can i include the table footer row to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action would be to use the provided GridOption exporterPdfFooter.

i.e. gridOptions.exporterPdfFooter = 'This is my footer';

As seen in the API [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions)

And in the tutorial [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data)

The Angular UI-Grid is excellent choice for a data grid not only for the range of functionality provided but also the [*robust documentation and tutorial set provided*](http://ui-grid.info/). Definitely worth a read.

Also if looking for a more detailed answer I would recommend a more detailed question including if possible code samples and/or a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or similar

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I tried to add it to the pdf footer.  There are two issues: 1. the total is repeated on every page. 2. it is hard to align the total line with the exiting table.   Actually, I found a workaround by manipulating docDefinition inside of exporterPdfCustomFormatter method.  Basically, calculate the column values and create a json object and add it to the table bottom row in the doc definition.  This resolved the issue.

Comment: @estick Did you run into cannot read property _span of undefined, trying to push to the bottom of the body.table and I get the _span undefined? I realize you haven't been active in a few months just a long shot.

Comment: The length of the array you push in docDefinition.content[0].table.body should be the same length as the other items in that array. Otherwise you get the _span is undefined exception.

Comment: I couldn't figure how to do this actually. I am including the footer in my ui-grid and can not export it as pdf or csv with the grid. Any explanation to how to do it please?

Comment: Did you set your footer using exporterPdfFooter in gridOptions and import 'ui.grid.exporter'? See the [exporting data tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data) for a working example.

Comment: yes, set the footer using exporterPdfFooter exporting the grid through passing it in exportGridPd functionf;